# Инстанцирование шаблонов C++

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

У меня есть следующий код:

```
namespace STDAllocators
{

    template<class Derived>
    struct IAllocator
    {
        typename Derived::pointer allocate(size_t count_objects);
        void deallocate(typename Derived::pointer memory_pointer, size_t count_objects);
    };

    template<typename T>
    class LinearAllocator : public IAllocator<LinearAllocator<T>>
    {
    public:
        using value_type    = T;
        using pointer       = T*;
        using const_pointer = const T*;
    public:
        LinearAllocator();
        LinearAllocator(const LinearAllocator& other);
        template<typename U>
        LinearAllocator(const LinearAllocator<U>& other);
        pointer allocateImpl(size_t count_objects);
        void deallocateImpl(pointer memory_pointer, size_t count_objects);
    };

}
```

И вот при инстанцировании шаблонов получаю не совсем понятную мне ошибку:

```
error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct STDAllocators::IAllocator<STDAllocators::LinearAllocator<int> >’
class LinearAllocator : public IAllocator<LinearAllocator<T>>
```

Кто-нибудь может подсказать в чем проблема?

Comment: На английском SO похожий вопрос есть: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006614/c-static-polymorphism-crtp-and-using-typedefs-from-derived-classes

Comment: при чем тут  английское SO? Давайте тогда находить ответы в разных сайтах, вместо того, чтоб отвечать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело в том, что при использовании в списке базовых классов тип `LinearAllocator<T>` является неполным (incomplete ), т.е. как при наличии только предварительного объявления `template<typename T> class LinearAllocator;`. А для инстанцирования класса `IAllocator` должно быть доступна информации о наличии типа `pointer` в `LinearAllocator`.

Простейшим решением в такой ситуации может быть перенос (части) объявлений типов в базовый класс:

```
template<typename Derived, typename T> // Derived в такой форме оказывается не нужным
struct IAllocator
{
    using value_type    = T;
    using pointer       = T*;
    using const_pointer = const T*;

    pointer allocate(size_t count_objects);
    void deallocate(pointer memory_pointer, size_t count_objects);
};

template<typename T>
class LinearAllocator : public IAllocator<LinearAllocator<T>, T>
{
public: using t_Allocator =  IAllocator<LinearAllocator<T>, T>;
public: using typename t_Allocator::value_type;
public: using typename t_Allocator::pointer;
public: using typename t_Allocator::const_pointer;
public:
    LinearAllocator();
    LinearAllocator(const LinearAllocator& other);
    template<typename U>
    LinearAllocator(const LinearAllocator<U>& other);
    pointer allocateImpl(size_t count_objects);
    void deallocateImpl(pointer memory_pointer, size_t count_objects);
};
```

или в дополнительный класс типажа:

```
template<typename Allocator>
struct AllocatorTraits;

template<typename Derived>
struct IAllocator
{
    typename AllocatorTraits<Derived>::pointer allocate(size_t count_objects);
    void deallocate(typename AllocatorTraits<Derived>::pointer memory_pointer, size_t count_objects);
};

template<typename T>
class LinearAllocator;

template<typename T>
struct AllocatorTraits<LinearAllocator<T>>
{
    using value_type    = T;
    using pointer       = T*;
    using const_pointer = const T*;
};

template<typename T>
class LinearAllocator : public IAllocator<LinearAllocator<T>>
{
public: using value_type = typename AllocatorTraits<LinearAllocator>::value_type;
public: using pointer = typename AllocatorTraits<LinearAllocator>::pointer;
public: using const_pointer = typename AllocatorTraits<LinearAllocator>::const_pointer;
public:
    LinearAllocator();
    LinearAllocator(const LinearAllocator& other);
    template<typename U>
    LinearAllocator(const LinearAllocator<U>& other);
    pointer allocateImpl(size_t count_objects);
    void deallocateImpl(pointer memory_pointer, size_t count_objects);
};
```

Comment: Часто определения выносят в отдельный класс и обозначают как  Trait и ингда заворачивают в область имен для "внутренних" компонентов, а этот класс может использоваться повторно везде где нужно. Упс, комментарий устарел )